# code execution not working as the code doesnt result in the box being displayed red

Tags: javascript, html, css

Execution method Unsure of whether it is executing the Java script

```
        form.addEventListener('Submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault():
            checkInputs();
        
        });
```

Function used to check the inputs from the html file

```
        function checkInputs() {
            // get the values form the inputs
            const firstnameValue = first.value.trim();
            const lastnameValue = second.value.trim();
            const numberValue = phone.value.trim();
            const amountValue = amount.value.trim();
```

Conditional that have to be met

```
            if(firstnameValue === '') {
                // show error
                // add error class
                setErrorFor(Forename, "Username is invlaid");
            } else {
                // add success class
                setSucessFor(Forename);
            }
        }
```

Unsure of why the function is not working

```
        function setErrorFor(input, message) {
            const formControl = input.parentElement; // .form-control
            const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
        
            // add error message inside small
            small.innerText = message;
        
            // add errror class
            formControl.className = 'form-control error';
        }
```

Comment: `Submit` event listener starts with lower case like `submit`

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: Give whole code or codepen or other hosting webiste